# Retrieving attribute from checkbuttons - Tkinter, checkbuttons, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

I am trying to make a todo-program. Every `Task` has some attributes, one of them is a *value* based on some of the user input.
When you're adding a *New Task* there's an option to check all existing tasks which the new task could be somehow related to (e.g. maybe the New Task is to do the dishes and one of the existing tasks is to buy soap for it - so they're related somehow).

Here's a picture if it clarifies anything:

[image: Picture of UI, simplified]

Let's say I have 3 boxes/existing tasks checked.
I want to retrieve each value attribute (`val_var` in code) associated with each of the checked task  buttons. The sum of all the checked task-values will then be an attribute, *connectivity*, of the New Task currently being added.

However, I am not sure how I can "grab" all the checkbutton-values of the buttons that have been checked even though it most likely is a trivial issue.

Simplified code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label, Canvas, OptionMenu, Toplevel, Checkbutton
import tkinter.messagebox 


task_list = []
task_types = ['Sparetime', 'School', 'Work']

class Task:
    def __init__(self, n, h, v,):
        self.name = n
        self.hours = h
        self.value = v
        #self.connectivity = c


def show_tasks():
    task = task_list[-1]

    print('\n')
    print('Value:')
    print(task.value)


def open_add_task():
    taskwin = Toplevel(root)
    taskwin.focus_force()
    
    #Name
    titlelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Title task concisely:', font=('Roboto',11,'bold')).grid(column=1, row=0)
    name_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=40, justify='center')
    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    #HOURS(required)
    hourlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Whole hours \n required', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=1, row=16)
    hour_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=4, justify='center')
    hour_entry.grid(column=1, row=17)

    #CONNECTIVITY
    C_lab = Label(taskwin,text="Check tasks this task is related to").grid(column=1, row=18)
    placement=19
    for task in task_list:
        Checkbutton(taskwin, text=(task.name)).grid(column=1, row=placement, sticky="w")
        placement+=1

    def add_task():
        if name_entry.get() != '': 

            val_var = (int(hour_entry.get())/10)
                
            task_list.append(Task(name_entry.get(), hour_entry.get(), val_var))
            show_tasks()
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, name_entry.get())
            name_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            taskwin.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')

        
    Add_button = Button(taskwin, text='Add', font=('Roboto',10), command=add_task).grid(column=2, row=placement, sticky="e")
    placement+=1
    

root = Tk()

task_frame = Frame()
# Create UI
your_tasks_label = Label(root, text='THESE ARE YOUR TASKS:', font=('Roboto',10, 'bold'), justify='center')
your_tasks_label.pack()

listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(root, height=10, width=50, font=('Roboto',10), justify='center')
listbox_tasks.pack()

#BUTTONS
New_Task_Button = Button(root, text='New Task', width=42, command=open_add_task)
New_Task_Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you reduced the code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about getting values from a list of checkboxes, we don't need any of the code related to tasks. Try to simplify your problem with a frame, the checkbuttons, and just a little more code to make it all work.

Comment: Thanks. 
I am sorry. I have edited it and simplified it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to hold tkinter `DoubleVar` which is used in each task's `Checkbutton` with its `value` as the `onvalue` option.  Then you can sum all the values in the list of `DoubleVar` to get the `connectivity`.

Below is a modified example based on your code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label, Canvas, OptionMenu, Toplevel, Checkbutton, DoubleVar
import tkinter.messagebox


task_list = []
task_types = ['Sparetime', 'School', 'Work']

class Task:
    def __init__(self, n, h, v, c): # enable the "connectivity"
        self.name = n
        self.hours = h
        self.value = v
        self.connectivity = c

    # added to show the task details
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: hours={self.hours}, value={self.value}, connectivity={self.connectivity}"


def show_tasks():
    task = task_list[-1]
    print(task)  # show the task details


def open_add_task():
    taskwin = Toplevel(root)
    taskwin.focus_force()

    #Name
    titlelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Title task concisely:', font=('Roboto',11,'bold')).grid(column=1, row=0)
    name_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=40, justify='center')
    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    #HOURS(required)
    hourlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Whole hours \n required', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=1, row=16)
    hour_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=4, justify='center')
    hour_entry.grid(column=1, row=17)

    #CONNECTIVITY
    C_lab = Label(taskwin,text="Check tasks this task is related to").grid(column=1, row=18)
    placement=19
    vars = [] # list to hold the DoubleVar used by Checkbutton
    for task in task_list:
        # add a DoubleVar to the list
        vars.append(DoubleVar())
        # use the task.value as the "onvalue" option
        Checkbutton(taskwin, text=task.name, variable=vars[-1], onvalue=task.value, offvalue=0).grid(column=1, row=placement, sticky="w")
        placement+=1

    def add_task():
        if name_entry.get() != '':

            val_var = (int(hour_entry.get())/10)
            # calculate the "connectivity" of the new task
            connectivity = sum(v.get() for v in vars)

            task_list.append(Task(name_entry.get(), hour_entry.get(), val_var, connectivity))
            show_tasks()
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, name_entry.get())
            name_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            taskwin.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')


    Add_button = Button(taskwin, text='Add', font=('Roboto',10), command=add_task).grid(column=2, row=placement, sticky="e")
    placement+=1


root = Tk()

task_frame = Frame()
# Create UI
your_tasks_label = Label(root, text='THESE ARE YOUR TASKS:', font=('Roboto',10, 'bold'), justify='center')
your_tasks_label.pack()

listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(root, height=10, width=50, font=('Roboto',10), justify='center')
listbox_tasks.pack()

#BUTTONS
New_Task_Button = Button(root, text='New Task', width=42, command=open_add_task)
New_Task_Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```